# How to get an id from view binding in when case?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view, android-viewbinding

How to change
`v.getId()`
in view binding when using when case on kotlin, i didn't found any answer and i'm new to view binding

Comment: Hi can you share your complete use case ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In Java

```
binding.yourView.getId()
```

In Kotlin

```
binding.yourView.id
```